# mongodb TTL doesnt expire nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, ttl

Im trying to add data that auto expire key value to my mongo db. 
im using mongo 3.1.3.
 i see my data get added on mlab, but it doesnt expire. what am i doing wrong? Ive searched through 20 diff pages, and no one seems to show a non-mongoose method that shows a collection being added with more than just "createdAt" key value which to me is pointless if i cannot add my own key value pair.

```
db.collection("myCol")
    .insertOne({
        "mykey": "myvalue"
    }, function (err, response) {
        return res.status(200).send("done")
    })
return db.collection("myCol")
    .createIndex({ "createdAt": 1 }, { expireAfterSeconds: 60 })
```

[Edit]
whats the correct format to delete "myCol" after 60 seconds?

`db.collection("myCol")
    .createIndex({ "createdAt": 1 }, { expireAfterSeconds: 60 })
    .insertOne({
    "mykey": "myvalue"
    }, function (err, response) {
    return res.status(200).send("done")
    })`
is invalid.

when you say "indexed field with matching Date values."... do you mean...

```
`db.collection("myCol")
    .insertOne({
        "mykey": "myvalue"
        "date": new Date()
    }, function (err, response) {
        return res.status(200).send("done")
    })
db.collection("myCol")
    .createIndex({ "createdAt": 1,  "date": new Date() }, { expireAfterSeconds: 60 })`
```

which is also invalid. i just need an example. docs arent clear either

Comment: The example document you are inserting in the current question doesn't include a `createdAt` field, so cannot expire automatically. A TTL index will only expire documents that have the indexed field with matching Date values. If this isn't the issue, can you edit your question to include an example of a document you expect to expire that isn't working?  Also note that the TTL index background thread runs every 60 seconds, so if you are testing a short expiry you may have to wait up to a minute to confirm the outcome.

Comment: updated the above question in the main question. i still dont know how to set "createAt" and my own key value pair to expire after 60 seconds.

Comment: You don't need to call the index `createdAt` - you need to call it the same as the data property you have. In your case, that would be `date` (This is what @Stennie's comment was trying to explain: you were creating an index with a property called `createdAt` and yet your document had no such property). That said: You've given a few examples where you say "it's invalid" but what does that mean? Do you get an error when inserting documents? When trying to create an index? Please edit to clarify, and also include the error you're getting.  property.

Comment: i just need a non mongoose example of how to set it correctly.

invalid means, createIndex() and InsertOne() is not stackable. so after createIndex, theres no such InsertOne() function exists. or after InsertOne, there's no such createIndex() exists.

can someone show me how to create a doc and set a TTL. no mongoose? 
I do appreciate all the help, but I guess im not getting my point across of what the heck im doing wrong?